# LDA topic distribution at training process and inference process

Tags: lda

I have a question about LDA, a popular topic modeling technique.

A LDA model is created from a certain training documents set. 
Then, topic distribution over documents of a data set which is same with the one used for training process is inferred based on the LDA model.

In this case, is the topic distribution created at the training process same with the one created at the inference process?

I'm asking it, because I have tried [plda](https://code.google.com/p/plda/wiki/PLDAQuickStart). It does not output the topic distribution at the training process, but outputs at the inferring process. Thus, I think if created topic distributions are almost identical, I can use plda even it has no output at training process.

Comment: Yep, that's the idea - in fact, when creating output during the training process the algorithm basically goes through an inference process. Just remember when inferencing the LDA model on any (other) corpus - the test data must come from the same dictionary (in mallet it is implemented through --use-pipe-from). I should also mention that I am not exactly familiar with plda but the algorithm is supposed to work this way unless there is coding error. Check resultant topics if they make sense - good test.